# Can I change the default translation plane? (v3.2.1)

Tags: interface, transforms, gizmo

When I make a selection and then press G for the translation tool, it defaults to using the viewport plane as the translation plane. Is there a way I could change the default behaviour to something else?

For example if my viewport is currently looking mostly down the Y axis, have that axis be the locked axis by default so my selection is translating along the XZ plane.

Failing this, is there a hotkey for the combined transform gizmo?
I have only found shortcuts for the individual elements (G=translate, S=scale, R=rotate).

Comment: G and then shift + z to translate in x and y, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple gizmos can be activated here:

[image]

If only transform is active, you can move the object in plane by clicking on one of the squares:

[image]

Comment: This isn't "exactly" what I was looking for, but it does the solve the problem, thanks!